# Android: SplashScreen keeps Loading No Matter What I Do

Tags: java, android, android-activity, splash-screen

Let's try to make it easy to understand.

For an Example I got "Page1" and "Page2" And "Page3".
OK. I created a splash screen on "Page2", so the user can see "Page2" for a specific time (5seconds). and it auto directs him to "Page3" and I also added two buttons on "Page2" so the user can either click "Button1" that goes to "Page3" quicker. or "Button2" that goes to "Page 1"
Ok i done that all correct.
But if "Page2" is on and the user doesnt touch anything it takes him to "Page3".. my problem is that the user can touch anything "Button1" or "Button2" it directs him to "Page3", and if he touches "Button2" and goes to "Page1" (after the timelimit of splashscreen on "Page2" is up, it auto directs him from "Page1" to "Page3"

Please Help.

My Code Is

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;



public class StartGame extends Activity {

    // ===========================================================
    // Fields
    // ===========================================================

    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT = 3000;

    // ===========================================================
    // "Constructors"
    // ===========================================================

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.startgame);

        /* New Handler to start the Menu-Activity 
         * and close this Splash-Screen after some seconds.*/
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(StartGame.this,Fail.class);
                StartGame.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
                StartGame.this.finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
```

Please Help, Thanks.
Wahid

EDIT:

sorry I'm a beginner and I really don't know how to create variables,
Please if you can share some of your knowledge with me and show me an source code.

If variables mean buttons., that's already in there but i didn't

Answer (score 3):

You need to cancel the postDelayed call if your activity 2 has been stopped by the click of a button.

So first you need to create variables from your runnable and your handler.

and then on the press of either button you'll be able to call :

```
myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
```

Which will stop it from triggering if it is not suppose to anymore.

Edit to suit the beginner profile of the OP :

```
    myRunnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(StartGame.this,Fail.class);
            StartGame.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            StartGame.this.finish();
        }
    }

    myHandler = new Handler();
    myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGHT);
```